# How to make a jersey servlet responsible for any request?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, war

Imagine the following situation:
A webapplication gets deployed to a tomcat server. A jersey servlet is started that serves requests at `http://localhost/myServlet`

Now, when somebody is requesting 
`http://localhost/myServlet/this/path/shall/be/handled`, the myServlet should feel responsible for this request and handle it appropiately.

Edit: To be more specific: I do NOT know the path the user is requesting. Think about this like a virtual file system where the user requests `myServlet/path/to/file`. MyServlet shall be responsible for this GET request. As you can see mapping those URLs to Annotations is not possible. I'd like to annotate like `myServlet/*`, if that is more understandable.

Could anybody point me to the right direction? I feel a bit lost, but I am quite sure this is possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jersey Servlet (com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet) is the end point for REST API (if we are using Jersey REST) Call. So, When ever the servlet get any request , The same request is been processed by its Handler.

When the application get a request with myServlet with the appropriate url-pattern then Its corresponding Handler will activate and process the request for the appropriate response.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not know the pattern during development. The only thing I know is that it should not be more than 3 levels deep, so `myServlet/path/to/file` might be enough. Still, it could be `myServlet/who/am/I.jpg` or `myServlet/areallylong.text/with-characters` or just `myServlet/file.extension`

Comment: Nevermind, I should have taken more care when reading your answer. You provided all necessary information, I was expecting a ready to work solution, but actually your response forced me to dive into it and I figured that you are allowed to use regular expressions within url-pattern.
Good job :-)